# How to share lock between threads started by instances of different classes in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I tried creating a shared lock in the Application class and passing it to the method parameter that creates a thread and uses this lock. I want a thread created by an instance of a class to synchronize with a thread created by an instance of another class.

Class Alpha has a start(Object sharedLock) which creates a new thread.

```
public abstract class Alpha {
   public abstract void test();

   public void start(Object sharedLock) {
      Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
         while(true) {
            synchronized(sharedLock) {
               test();
            }
            try {
               TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(db.timeInterval)
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                 Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
      })
   }
}
```

Class Alpha has two base classes Beta and Gama, which invokes start() method from Application class. Below is the code snippet

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) {
    beta.start(sharedLock);
    gama.start(sharedLock)
}
```

test() is overridden in child classes - beta and gama.

And here is the implementation of test()

```
public class Beta extends Aplha {
   @Override
   public void test() {
      ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
      final int[] count = {1};
   
      Runnable task = new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            System.out.println(count[0]);
            count[0]++;

            if (count[0] > 20) {
               executor.shutdown();
            }
         }
      }
      executor.scheduledAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
}

public class Gama extends Alpha {
   @Override
   public void test() {
      System.out.println("Gama thread")
   }
}
```

Only one thread should be able to execute test() at a time. So if beta thread calls start() first then it should print 1 to 20 and then gama thread execute start()

Also, when a thread is seeping, the other thread can execute by having access to lock

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: I'm afraid you need a little more than an `Object` to do what you want to do

Comment: `can I make the gama thread wait until beta finishes` One way to do that is just use a single thread.  If you want sequential semantics like this, a single thread of execution does that naturally.

Comment: P.S. I don't like your one space indentation.  Please use at least two spaces.  I prefer three myself.

Comment: The reason for using multiple thread is time interval of execution of test() will be different.

Comment: Are you saying that each of the two threads is `synchronized` on the same `sharedLock` object at the same time? That seems unlikely. What makes you think they both are synchronized on the same object at the same time? Can you expand your example to something that other people can try out for themselves? http://sscce.org/

Comment: I am not sure about that. What I know for sure is that if both thread were operating on the same shared space then this would work. But I have two different instances and that is my question- how can I share lock between threads started by different instances

Comment: P.S., You said, "how can I make the gama thread wait until...?" IMO, saying, "wait" to talk about `synchronized` blocks is a red flag. If one thread has to wait for to enter a synchronized block, that's a necessary evil, not desirable behavior. You should always try to minimize that wait. When `synchronized` (or `ReentrantLock`) appears in your code, it sends a message to other programmers: It says, "This protects shared data from corruption." If you want to tell other programmers, "This thread must wait until..." then you should use something else (probably from `java.util.concurrent`.)

Comment: Re, "how can I share lock between threads started by different instances?" Your code already _appears_ (from what we can see of it) to do that. Your `run` method clearly passes the same argument to `beta.start` and `gama.start`. If both of those `start` methods look like the one that you showed, then they're both `synchronized` on the same shared lock. Like I said above, if you could amend your question with an example that other people here could run and demonstrate the problem for themselves, then you would be more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Sorry but if they both are synchronized on the same shared lock, should not only one thread execute start() at a time? I have added the implementation of the start() method for both classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try a semaphore:

```
public static void start(Semaphore sharedLock) {
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                sharedLock.acquire();
                test();
                sharedLock.release();
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    start(semaphore);
    start(semaphore);
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I can see logs of gama thread while beta thread is still executing test()

Comment: The problem is elsewhere then

Comment: Could you explain how your example would function differently from OP's example? What would `acquire`ing and then `release`ing a shared `Semaphore` make your program do differently from OP's code that enters and leaves a block that is `synchronized` on a shared `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

> I have added the implementation of the `start()` method for both classes."

Actually, no. You added the `test` methods. But no matter because...

> Only one thread should be able to execute test() at a time. So if beta thread calls start() first then it should print 1 to 20 and then gama thread execute start()

Your `beta.test()` method doesn't print anything. It creates a new `ScheduledExecutorService`, and it submits a task to it. The scheduled executor performs that task in a completely different thread, and the task makes no reference whatever to the `sharedLock` object.